# How to query a property that is not part of the model in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a `User` entity that contains the username, name and other **non sensitive** information.

During authentication, I need to query the password (hashed) and the password salt in order to do a hash comparison. Those two properties are not part of the model due to their sensitive nature.

How can I query those two properties in NHibernate without using `CreateSQLQuery`? I now that `CreateSQLQuery` works, but I was trying to find a non SQL way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a DTO that would be mapped to the same table as `User`, and will only be used for this purpose, and use that.
for example-

```
public class AuthUserDTO
{
   public virtual string Username {get; set;}
   public virtual string PasswordHash {get; set;}
   public virtual string Salt {get; set;}
}
```

all of your 'regular' methods would return a regular `User` object, except for `GetUserForAuthentication` that would return an `AuthUserDTO`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use query only properties in your mapping file, using the "access" attribute. E.g. in your hbm file:

```
<property name="PasswordHash" type="string" column="PasswordHash" access="none" />
```

This will allow you to query PasswordHash in a HQL or Criteria query as if it were a normal property, but you don't actually have a PasswordHash property in your user class.

Comment: How would you define such property in "loquacious" mapping?

Comment: Not sure I'm afraid, haven't used Loquacious